# String ID format checking and padding in R

Tags: r, string, input

Some codes are formatted as numbers divided by dashes (e.g., Social Security Numbers are typically formatted "ddd-dd-dddd", where d stands for any digit; denote this in short 3-2-4 format, standing for the number of digit in each "chunk").

I need to input product codes which come at 5-4, 4-4 or 5-3 format, and then:
(a) validate that they conform to any of these format, and (b) pad with zeros, so that the output is in 5-4 format.

Here is a code that does that. Is there a nicer way? how can it be vectorized?

```
library(stringr)

as_product_code <- function(x) {
  # Clean Product Codes
  #  Input: 5-4, 5-3, or 4-4 product code.
  #  Output: 5-4 product code.

  chunks <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = "-", fixed = T))
  if (length(chunks == 2) & (identical(nchar(chunks), c(5L, 3L)) |
                             identical(nchar(chunks), c(5L, 4L)) |
                             identical(nchar(chunks), c(4L, 4L)))) {
    output_code<- paste(str_pad(chunks[1], pad = "0", width = 5),
                        str_pad(chunks[2], pad = "0", width = 4),
                        sep = "-")
    return(output_code)
  } else {
    warning("Unexpected format. Doing nothing.")
    return(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: In my sense, this is already quite vectorized ! What I'd only do is remove the `library(stringr)` in the function (and put it above)

Comment: @AntoinePissoort it doesn't work on, e.g. `x=c("1234-1234","1234-1234")`

Comment: @AntoinePissoort and I've edited to reflect your other suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and the `stringr`-package. This will return NA for a entry which does not follow the specified pattern.

For regular expression have a look at the [cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf).

`\\d` stands for any digit (0-9) and the number in the brackets { } give the number of repetions (either {min, max} or {exact}). The `^` means, that I'm looking at the beginning of the string and `$` marks the end. Thus I don't match the string with ab at the end.

```
test <- c("1234-1234", "12345-123", "12345-1234ab", "12345-1234", "1234-123")

ifelse(str_detect(test, "^(\\d{4,5})-(\\d{4})$|^(\\d{5})-(\\d{3})$"), 
       str_replace_all(test, c("^(\\d{4})-" = "0\\1-", "-(\\d{3})$" = "-0\\1")), 
       NA)

[1] "01234-1234" "12345-0123" NA           "12345-1234" NA
```

Comment: great approach. but it passes 4-3 as correct input.

Comment: Oh yes that's true, I did a quick fix. There might be a more elegant solution to the validation of the input. In would get messier with more possible combinations but for your problem it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

We can actually take advantage of the `dataframe` structure here to get some vectorization help.

```
# Create reproducible example
set.seed(9025)

d1 = sample(1:5, 1e5, replace=TRUE)
d2 = sample(1:5, 1e5, replace=TRUE)
codes = sapply(1:1e5, function(i) {
  c1 = paste0(sample(1:9, d1[i]), collapse='')
  c2 = paste0(sample(1:9, d2[i]), collapse='')
  paste(c1, c2, sep='-')
})

library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

# Create our dataframe, separate the product code, pad the values,
# and use vectorized ifelse to "remove" bad product codes.
output = codes %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  separate(value, into=c('c1', 'c2'), sep='-', remove=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(include = ifelse(nchar(c1) %in% 4:5 & 
                          nchar(c2) %in% 3:4 & 
                          (nchar(c1) + nchar(c2) > 7), 
                          1, 0),
         c1 = str_pad(c1, width=5, side='left', pad=0),
         c2 = str_pad(c2, width=4, side='right', pad=0),
         code = paste(c1, c2, sep='-')) %>%
  mutate(code = ifelse(include == 1, code, '')) %>%
  pull(code)

head(codes)

[1] "62971-2"   "5-51864"   "32419-328" "931-8"    
[5] "18324-248" "8-628" 

head(output)

[1] ""           ""           "32419-3280"
[4] ""           "18324-2480" ""
```

Comment: This doesn't validate the input and pads incorrectly. E.g., "1234-123" becomes "01234-1230".

Comment: @dzeltzer A little clunky in terms of the validation logic, but the updated code incorporates your validation logic.

Comment: @dzeltzer For some reason, the final change I made this morning wasn't applied to my edits, which would have resulted in incorrect output. The code as it is now should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Vectorize` base R function:

```
as_product_code <- function(x) {
#your function
}

x <- c('1234-1234','1234-1234')

as_product_code_vec <- Vectorize(as_product_code,'x',USE.NAMES = F)
as_product_code_vec(x)
```